# Difference between cloud server and database

Tags: web-services

Can any one explain me the difference between :-
1.CLOUD.
2.SERVER.
3.DATABASE
Hi have seen lots of people defining cloud as a server then why it is called cloud , I mean there is some difference between them

Answer (score 0):

A [Database](http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/definition/database) is most of the time a service. For example, a [mysql](https://www.mysql.com/) services which runs on a server. In a database you store for example information about user in a table in case it is a relational database like MySQL, PostgreSQL or others.

 A [server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_(computing)) is a computer build for professional use. Google use for example a lot of servers. On a server you can enable a lot of services (Printserver,...). As a normal person you can buy a server but it is not really necessary.

The word "Cloud" is currently a buzzword. Companies like VMware use the word "Cloud" for marketing. Every company use the word "Cloud" different.
VMware - Hybrid-cloud, Private-Cloud
http://www.vmware.com/solutions/cloud-computing.html

Cloud is sometimes also a other word for [Paas, Saas or Iaas](https://apprenda.com/library/paas/iaas-paas-saas-explained-compared/). For instance [Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/) is in my opinion Iaas.

*Hope that it is now clear. Lookup the links to understand the topic more.*

Comment: So that means cloud and server is almost same ,and different company just name it differently.

Comment: A cloud is often a lot of servers